# jQuery - Add cross-browser css styles to an element

Tags: jquery, css

i created a button generator with jQuery and want to add styles for multiple browsers to an element. I do this with this code:

```
    jQuery('.previewButton').css('background','');
    var s = jQuery('.bg_start_color').val();
    var e = jQuery('.bg_end_color').val();
    jQuery('.previewButton').css('background-color',s);
    jQuery('.previewButton').css('background','-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from('+s+'), to('+e+'))');
    jQuery('.previewButton').css('background','-webkit-linear-gradient(top,'+s+', '+e+')');
    jQuery('.previewButton').css('background','-moz-linear-gradient(top,'+s+','+e+')');
    jQuery('.previewButton').css('background','-ms-linear-gradient(top,'+s+','+e+')');
    jQuery('.previewButton').css('background','-o-linear-gradient(top,'+s+','+e+')');
```

The problem i face is that when i use it in Safari the -webkit- style is applied to the element .previewButton. When i use the generator in Firefox the -moz- style is applied to the button. I want to save the button in the database and surely want to save all cross-browser relevant styles and not only the one i'm working on right now.

But why are only the browser-relevant styles applied to the element if the code says that all should be applied? How can i change that? Does somebody know?

Thanks.

Comment: Only the browser specific styles are applied because that's all the browser itself cares about. Web browsers interpret what they know, and ignore anything they do not. I'm not sure what you mean by "saving the button in the database" though, could you elaborate on that more?

Comment: Yes, sure. I want to add the previewButton, including the styles the user has applied, to the database. Surely the user should save a button's style that can be interpreted by all browsers not only the one that the user is working on.

Comment: What database? How are you saving to this database? It sounds like you need to save the styles to the database directly, rather than interpreting the browser's styling.

Comment: Yes. I created a workaround that the styles that should be applied to the button are stored in a normal text field and the value of the textfield is saved to the database...that works.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the colour values and then when you write the style to database, include all of the broswer specific styles in the css - not just the style currently applied to the button

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will only apply CSS styles that they understand. For example, Safari doesn't understand styles with the `-moz-` or `-ms-` prefix, so it just ignores them. That's why it probably doesn't show up in your web inspector. That doesn't mean your cross-browser styles aren't there though. It just means your current browser isn't looking at them because it doesn't understand them.

Don't worry, everything is working correctly.